# how can i put this php code as a smarty code?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to use smarty but I want to know how can I convert this php code to smarty code :s, thanks

```
<?php
    include_once("paypalewp.php");
    $paypal = new paypalewp();
    $paypal->setTempFileDirectory("/tmp");
    $paypal->setCertificate("my-pubcert.pem", "my-prvkey.pem");
    $paypal->setCertificateID("DFGY7654567");
    $paypal->setPayPalCertificate("paypal_cert_pem.txt");
    $parameters = array(
        "cmd" => "_xclick",
        "item_name" => "$item",
        "currency_code" => "USD",
    );
    $encryptedButton = $paypal->encryptButton($parameters);
    echo $encryptedButton; 
?>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What do you mean "convert this php to smarty"? Smarty is a templating engine, and your current code is all backend stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This code should not be put into a Smarty template at all.

You should be assigning `$encryptedButton` to a Smarty variable for display in your template (`$smarty->assign('encryptedButton', $encryptedButton);`), but the rest of the code should be good old regular PHP in a non-Smarty file.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i want to loop this?

Comment: Make `$encryptedButton` an array and pass it to the template.